# A little confused about the complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

In textbook, a complex function can be expressed:$z=x+iy,f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$. It inputs a complex numbe, then outputs a complex number. Why can it not be expressed as $f(z)=u(x)+iv(y)$, it also inputs a complex numbe, then outputs a complex number. What is the problem of my idea (definition)?

Comment: Try $\;f(z) = i\,z\;$ for example. There is no reason why $\,\operatorname{Re}\big(f(z)\big)\,$ has to depend on $\,\operatorname{Re}(z)\,$ alone.

Comment: Your expression is a special case of the one in the book. It is a complex function, but not all complex functions take your form.

Comment: Thank you@dxiv@Gary

Answer (score 3):

What you wrote, i.e. $f(z)=u(x)+i\,v(y)$ is just a very special possible function. In general however, $f(z)=u(x,y)+i\,v(x,y)$. For example:

$$f(z)=z^2=(x+iy)^2=(x^2-y^2)+i(2xy),$$
so $f(z)=u(x,y)+i\,v(x,y)$ where $u(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ and $v(x,y)=2xy$.

Comment: Click the green check if this answer does the job for you.